# How do I identify if a runc container is running as privileged?

Tags: docker, containerd, runc, cri-o

Regardless of docker/crio/containerd starting the container, is there a way to understand if the runc container is running as privileged one?

`docker inspect` does show privilegedness but I want to find out at the runc layer.

Answer (score 3):

The state and the configuration of every `runc` container may be obtained from the `$ROOT_DIR/$CONTAINER_ID/state.json` file, where `$ROOT_DIR` is a *root directory* for a group of containers (usually managed by a specific higher-level runtime like Docker). For example, on my machine Docker uses the root dir `/run/docker/runtime-runc/moby`, thus, I can find the `runc`-level configuration of some container as follows:

```sh
# jq .config /run/docker/runtime-runc/moby/$CONTAINER_ID/state.json
{
  "no_pivot_root": false,
  "parent_death_signal": 0,
  "rootfs": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<CONTAINER_ID>/merged",
  "readonlyfs": false,
...
}
```

You can easily find out that this file does not contain fields like `privileged`. A quick search through `runc` source code shows that it does not have a notion of a privileged container, i.e. this is an abstraction from the higher levels. This means, in turn, that there is no *simple* way to determine, whether the container was started as a privileged one or not, from the `runc` level.

However, it is still possible to say whether the container has *the same privileges* as those which are granted by `--privileged` argument at the Docker level: the `state.json` file contains a list of capabilities, granted to the container; a list of device nodes, available to the container; seccomp mode and so on. From practical standpoint, it is unwise to waste your time on checking all these settings, so it is better just to look at `docker inspect`.

Comment: I agree with the above. But working at the runc layer lets me compatible(to an extent) with docker, containerd and cri-o